# provide an interpretation for a given WFF

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

Provide a satisfying and falsifying interpretation for the following WFF:

```
∀x∀y(P(x,y) ↔ P(y,x))
```

my attempt:

x,y are numbers

P(x,y): x > y

falsifying intepretation:

x: 5

y: 3

so the function would be false because it would not work both ways for the ↔ connective.

Is my interpretation sound? or am I completely missing the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to produce (1) a **structure** in which the given sentence is true and (2) a structure in which it is false. By structure one means a non-empty set together with an interpretation of the binary predicate symbol $P$.

For true, let the underlying set be the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and let the interpretation of $P$ be the equality relation. If we call this structure $M$, it is clear that our sentence is true in $M$.

For false, let the underlying set be the same, and let the interpretation of $P$ be the ordinary $\lt$ relation. The given sentence is false in this structure.

Comment: in other words, the underlying set would be considered the Domain right?

Comment: It is often called the domain. "Underlying set" is also in common use.

Comment: so for ∀x∀y we consider the underlying set as a whole? however for an existential quantifier we only consider one element within the underlying set?

Comment: We are considering the truth or falsity of a sentence, and you know the truth condition for sentences that use universal quantifiers. For the second model, you would prove falsity in the model by showing that there are $a$ and $b$ in the model such that $P_M(a,b)$ holds in the model but $P_M(b,a)$ does not, where $P_M$ is the interpretation of $P$ in $M$.

Comment: So for example if I have : ∃x∃y(¬P(x,y) and we let the interpretation P to be the equality relation and the domain to be {1,2,3} then we can provide both a  satisfying and a falsifying interpretation under the same structure by choosing an x and y in the domain to satisfy and falsify the structure.